# does Linux kernel alter unmounted ext4 partitions?

Tags: linux, ext4

When the 4.9 Linux kernel boots and recognizes the presence of and MMC partition, does it alter the partition in any way if the partition is not mounted?

I pre-calculated the sha256 of a "filesystem.img" at build time (ext4.)

I apply my file system to an MMC partition as follows:

```
dd if=myfilesystem.img of=/dev/mmcblk0p2 bs=4096 count=XYZABC
```

I can read the partition back and verify that the flash was correct:

```
dd if=/dev/mmcblk0p2 bs=496 count=XYZABC | sha256sum
```

Journaling is disabled.  I can manually mount the file system read-only and unmount as much as I want.  The sha256 remains the same.

However, if I reboot and run the checksum again, the sha256 on the partition comes out different. The partition I wrote to before rebooting is not mounted.  But it is recognized as mmcblk0p2 by the kernel.

Does the kernel alter the data in a partition in any way before it is mounted?

Comment: when using `count=x`, you should also use `iflag=fullblock`. there is also a typo in your command (`bs=496` instead of `bs=4096`)

Answer (score 1):

Which distro / environment are you booting exactly?

It could be as simple as a filesystem check that just updates the last-checked timestamp. Instead of taking a hash sum, it would be more interesting to make a 1:1 copy and then compare them byte-by-byte (`cmp -l`) to find out what exactly changed.

Usually, it's not the kernel modifying the filesystems, but whatever userland you are booting into. Most LiveCDs (Live-USB-Sticks), even those made for rescue purposes, modify filesystems by mounting them in search of their own live data. With systemd/udev, there is also a lot of magic happening in the background that you might not be aware of.

If you are able to modify initramfs / early boot, try setting `/proc/sys/vm/block_dump` before anything else and you might get some surprises regarding what's writing where in `dmesg`.

Note: this will cause issues if you are already logging kernel messages to disk, as each write would cause another write for the log alone.

> I can manually mount the file system read-only and unmount as much as I want.

Even a read-only mount doesn't always guarantee no-change:

```
# truncate -s 100M foobar.iso
# losetup --find --show foobar.iso 
/dev/loop0
# mkfs.ext4 foobar.iso
# md5sum foobar.iso 
59dea589bb84855e282d1415b3238230  foobar.iso
# mount -o ro /dev/loop0 loop/
# md5sum /dev/loop0
47c89177d619b55b701a1ddbde352c90  /dev/loop0
```

What happened here? No idea, really...

```
--- a.txt   2018-12-26 20:39:13.578096660 +0100
+++ b.txt   2018-12-26 20:39:18.444742584 +0100
@@ -1536,11 +1536,10 @@
 *
 03000400  c0 3b 39 98 00 00 00 04  00 00 00 00 00 00 04 00  |.;9.............|
 03000410  00 00 10 00 00 00 00 01  00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00  |................|
-03000420  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 12 00 00 00 00  |................|
+03000420  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
 03000430  15 de d5 f7 6f 52 43 9b  a9 18 9b 3d 28 65 2d 51  |....oRC....=(e-Q|
 03000440  00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
-03000450  04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
-03000460  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
+03000450  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
 *
 03800400  58 64 00 00 00 90 01 00  00 14 00 00 40 6d 01 00  |Xd..........@m..|
 03800410  4d 64 00 00 01 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |Md..............|
```

If you want to reinforce the read-only idea a little, use `mount -o loop,ro`, it adds a read-only loop device in between. But even that is no guarantee for anything.

Comment: You can use `blockdev --setro` to have kernel enforce read-only status, even against its own facilities (eg a filesystem).

Comment: Fantastic!  blockdev --setro appears to have licked the problem.  "/dev/mmcblk0pX write protected."  on boot.  NOW the hash doesn't change.  Otherwise, I'll netcat the contents of my partition off the board and perform the byte-for-byte compare you are doing.  I'm  using Yocto distribution with an IMX6.